# %in%, == or something else to compare multiple values

Tags: r, vector

I think I'm still a little unclear on how R works on individual elements in vectorized statements.

I have the following code

```
df1$flag <- ifelse(df1$year < 2013 &
        df1$year == df2$year &
        as.character(df1$code) == as.character(df2$code), 'Y', df1$flag)
```

And I am operating on this data

```
year <- c(2011, 2012, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2016, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2010)
flag <- 'N'
code <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
df1 <- data.frame(year, flag, code)

rm(year)
rm(flag)
rm(code)

year <- c(2015, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2016, 2016, 2010)
code <- c(5, 7, 3, 2, 14, 99, 10)
df2 <- data.frame(year, code)

df1$flag <- ifelse(df1$year < 2013 &
                     df1$year == df2$year &
                     as.character(df1$code) == as.character(df2$code), 'Y', df1$flag)
```

I want this to be the output

```
> df1
   year flag code
1  2011    1    1
2  2012    Y    2
3  2011    Y    3
4  2013    1    4
5  2014    1    5
6  2016    1    6
7  2016    1    7
8  2015    1    8
9  2016    1    9
10 2010    Y   10
```

But instead I am getting this

```
> df1
   year flag code
1  2011    1    1
2  2012    1    2
3  2011    Y    3
4  2013    1    4
5  2014    1    5
6  2016    1    6
7  2016    1    7
8  2015    1    8
9  2016    1    9
10 2010    1   10
```

I want the `ifelse` statement to compare each element of `df1$year` and `df1$code` to each element of `df2$year` and `df2$code`, but it doesn't look like `==` or `%in%` will do that.

To put it another way, what I want is to compare the elements like this

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    for(z in 1:nrow(df2)) {
         if(df1$year[i] < 2013 & df1$year[i] == df2$year[z] & 
                            as.character(df1$code[i]) == as.character(df2$code[z]))
             df1$flag[i] <- 'Y'
    }
}
```

Obviously using `for` like this GREATLY slows down execution and cannot be used, but it doesn't seem like `==`, `%in%`, `identical()` or `all.equal()` will do what I describe in the `for` loop either.  How can I get the output I've described in R?

Comment: Whether your code is correct depends on what you're trying to achieve. What that is, is not clear for me.

Comment: @BobJansen I'm asking if the `ifelse` statement does what I describe more explicitly in the nested `for` loops.  I also corrected the `for` loops as I hadn't used specific indexing on them like I meant to, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you try with `dplyr::if_else` instead of `ifelse` ? Can you provide a reproducible example of the problem you're facing ?

Comment: @FlorianGD dplyr::if_else didn't fix it, but I updated my question with some example output.  The problem is that neither the `==` or `%in%` operators are doing what I describe in the nested `for` loops, and I'm not sure how to express that in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` compares two vectors element-wise (assuming they are of the same length, if not, the small vector will be recycled so that they are).

This means that your code:

```
df1$flag <- ifelse(df1$year < 2013 &
        df1$year == df2$year &
        as.character(df1$code) == as.character(df2$code), 'Y', df1$flag)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
         if(df1$year[i] < 2013 & df1$year[i] == df2$year[i] & 
            as.character(df1$code[i]) == as.character(df2$code[i]))
           df1$flag[i] <- 'Y'
}
```

Assuming that df1 and df2 have the same number of rows.

---

Update

This is a case for a `merge` and not `for loop` or `if else`. Basically, you want to merge the data sets on year and code and then if the year is less than 2013 assign a `'Y'` to flag.

So, I added an identifier to df2 like this:

```
year <- c(2015, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2016, 2016, 2010)
code <- c(5, 7, 3, 2, 14, 99, 10)
flag2 <- 'Y'
#make sure the flags are not factors
df2 <- data.frame(year, code, flag2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then you just do:

```
#merge on year and code
newdf <- merge(df1, df2, by = c('year', 'code'), all.x = TRUE)
#assign Y to flag if year < 2013 and flag2 == Y
newdf$flag[newdf$year < 2013 & newdf$flag2 == 'Y'] <- 'Y'
#delete flag2
newdf$flag2 <- NULL
newdf
```

Out

```
   year code flag
1  2010   10    Y
2  2011    1    N
3  2011    3    Y
4  2012    2    Y
5  2013    4    N
6  2014    5    N
7  2015    8    N
8  2016    6    N
9  2016    7    N
10 2016    9    N
```

Comment: Yea that's the problem, df1 and df2 have a different number of rows.  I updated my question with some sample data and output.

Comment: Thanks!  You're right, this is better approached as a merge.  I'm having a lot of trouble getting over my OOP mentality with R >.<  Thanks for taking the time to help out though!

Comment: Yeah, it is the same for me when I code in python :). Happy to help!